# How do I use "will" with tense changes in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, will-would

"The board will not oust him; therefore, he remains CEO."

I'm confused. Should it be: "The board will not oust him; therefore, he *will* remain CEO."

Can someone explain the grammar rules here?

Comment: He remains the CEO because the board won’t oust him.

Comment: Think of this sense of 'will not' as being synonymous with 'is not disposed / inclined to'.

Comment: You can say _he will remain CEO_ if you want to. It means the same thing as _He remains CEO_, so the second _will_ is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think of 'remains' as 'is still'. Does that make more sense to you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.